# How To Drag and Drop Images inside Canvas in WPF using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, wpf-controls

I am able to dynamically add images into the WPF Canvas control as child elements but failing to drag & drop those images inside the canvas. Please help me as how could i move or drag/drop images inside the canvas window.

Thanks in advance.

Below is what I have done so far:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvasImages" Height="325" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="430" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" AllowDrop="True" 
PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="MouseLeftButtonDown" 
PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="MouseLeftButtonUp" 
PreviewMouseMove="MouseMove" 
MaxWidth="430" MaxHeight="325" 
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
</Grid>

**Code**
OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
op.Title = "Select Multiple Pictures";
op.Multiselect = true;
op.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | 
*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";

foreach (string imageFile in op.FileNames)
{
 Image img = new Image();
 img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageFile));
 img.Height = 100;
 img.Width = 100;
 img.AllowDrop = true;
 Canvas.SetTop(img, y); //Setting up images to the Top position
 Canvas.SetLeft(img, x); //Setting up images to the left position
 canvasImages.Children.Add(img);
}

private new void MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, 
MouseButtonEventArgs 
e)
 {
  IsDragging = true;
  draggedItem = (UIElement)sender;
  itemRelativePosition = e.GetPosition(draggedItem);
}

private new void MouseMove(object sender, 
System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
 if (!IsDragging)
     return;
 Point canvasRelativePosition = e.GetPosition(canvasImages);
 Canvas.SetTop(draggedItem, canvasRelativePosition.Y - 
 itemRelativePosition.Y);
 Canvas.SetLeft(draggedItem, canvasRelativePosition.X - 
 itemRelativePosition.X);
}

private new void MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs  
e)
{
   if (!IsDragging)
     return;
   IsDragging = false;
}
```

Comment: You need to intercept the PreviewMouseDown and PreviewMouseMove events instead, otherwise you're just clicking/dragging across the image rather than the canvas.

Comment: Thanks @Mark for your response, i tried the same way as you said but still not getting it worked. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: Try posting code that uses those events and I'll take a look, I know it works because I've done it myself dozens of times.

Comment: **Below is the XAML Code**

Comment: Great :) Finally made it to work with your help !!! A big Thanks to you @Mark and really appreciate for all your hard work and guidance through getting me out of the issue i had.......Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, a few things wrong here...

1) Your mouse down handler has to be on the image, not the canvas, otherwise your code has no way of knowing which item is being dragged.

2) Once you've clicked on an image the handler should capture the mouse for the canvas so that you get all mouse move messages.

3) The Canvas MouseMove and MouseUp handlers then need to be handled accordingly.

4) The Canvas needs to have a background. If you don't give it a background then it's effectively transparent to the hit-testing and you won't get mouse messages for it. If you don't want it to have a visible background then set it to `Transparent`.

So your Canvas tag needs to look like this:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvasImages" Height="325" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="430" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" AllowDrop="True" 
    PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="CanvasImages_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" 
    PreviewMouseMove="CanvasImages_PreviewMouseMove" 
    MaxWidth="430" MaxHeight="325" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    Background="Transparent" />
```

And every image you create needs to have a handler set for it's MouseDown event:

```
img.MouseLeftButtonDown += Img_MouseLeftButtonDown;
```

Then it's just a matter is implementing your handlers like this:

```
private void Img_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.draggedItem = (UIElement)sender;
    itemRelativePosition = e.GetPosition(this.draggedItem);
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void CanvasImages_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.draggedItem == null)
        return;
    var newPos = e.GetPosition(canvasImages) - itemRelativePosition;
    Canvas.SetTop(this.draggedItem, newPos.Y);
    Canvas.SetLeft(this.draggedItem, newPos.X);
    canvasImages.CaptureMouse();
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void CanvasImages_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.draggedItem != null)
    {
        this.draggedItem = null;
        canvasImages.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great :) Finally made it to work with your help !!! A big Thanks to you @Mark and really appreciate for all your hard word and guidance through getting me out of the  issue i had.......Thanks

Comment: Glad to help, pls don't forget to flag it as the correct answer if you're satisfied with it as the answer. :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

@Mark, Here are the XAML code and the respective Class for your perusal. Basically I am allowing multiple selection of images by "OpenFileDialog()" and adding those images dynamically to Canvas control  as mentioned in my previous code, which then i am failing to drag around those images internally within the Canvas control.

**Below is the XAML Code**

```
<Window x:Class="PicturesMovement.CanvasControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Connectlite Clients" 
    Height="394" Width="445"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize">
   <Grid Margin="0,0,2,0" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static                  
     SystemColors.MenuBarBrushKey}}">
    <Button x:Name="Select" Content="Select" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
     Height="22"  Margin="329,328,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"                       
     Click="SelectImages"/>
    <Button x:Name="Cancel" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left"                       
     Margin="374,328,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="49" 
     Click="closeBox"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvasImages" Height="325" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
      Width="430" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
       AllowDrop="True"  PreviewMouseDown="PreviewMouseDown" 
         PreviewMouseUp="PreviewMouseUp"                     
         PreviewMouseMove="PreviewMouseMove" MaxWidth="430" 
        MaxHeight="325"                    
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**Below are the respective Class that triggers those Mouse Events**

```
public partial class CanvasControl : System.Windows.Window,          
         System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector {

   this.canvasImages.PreviewMouseDown += new                       
   System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler 
    (this.PreviewMouseDown);

   this.canvasImages.PreviewMouseUp += new                   
    System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler 
       (this.PreviewMouseUp);

   this.canvasImages.PreviewMouseMove += new 
    System.Windows.Input.MouseEventHandler        
        (this.PreviewMouseMove);
}
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated...Thanks